# jQuery - slider displays wrong images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jQuery slider behaves really weird. After hiding the first image it shows the second one, and then, when it should load the third one, it simply shows again the first image. I have no idea what is wrong with my code. Would you have any suggestions for me?

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var counter = 1;
    function slider() {
    counter++;
    alert(counter);
        $('.hiddenSlider').hide(500, function() {
            $('#hs'+counter+'.hiddenSlider').show(500);
        });
    }
    setInterval(slider,5000);
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="sliderWindow">
    <img class="hiddenSlider" id="hs1" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider/first.jpg" />
    <img class="hiddenSlider" id="hs2" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider/second.jpg" />
    <img class="hiddenSlider" id="hs3" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider/third.jpg" />
    <img class="hiddenSlider" id="hs4" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider/fourth.jpg" />
    <img class="hiddenSlider" id="hs5" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slider/fifth.jpeg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hiddenSlider {
    display:none;
}

.hiddenSlider:first-child {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: There is a javascript error in your browser console?

Comment: @MarioAraque No, there is no error.

Comment: any problem in alerts (counter value)

Comment: I dont understand why is your code fails in the third item. I see an error because you don't set "counter" to 1 when it's value is greater than 5 (it's not an img with id hs6).

Comment: No problem in alerts. I know there is no limit, but it fails before it even reaches the 5th element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could try a guess where the problem is.
Animations are running asynchronous, if not queued.
You are starting multiple animations, which may conflict.
I changed the hide function, to only match the visible item, and it seems to run good.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;

    function slider() {       
        $('#hs' + counter + '.hiddenSlider').hide(500, function () {
             counter++;   
            $('#hs' + counter + '.hiddenSlider').show(500);
        });
    }
    setInterval(slider, 1000);
});
```

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Drea/orxpf1vk/

Alternative with queue function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 1;

    function slider() {       
        $('#hs' + counter + '.hiddenSlider').hide(500).queue(function () {
            counter = counter % 5 + 1;                   
            $('#hs' + counter + '.hiddenSlider').show(500);                 
            $.dequeue(this);               
        });
    }
    setInterval(slider, 1000);
});
```